# How do I do a :g with a concatenating of submatches in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a file whose content is roughly something like

```
insert into FooBar values (13, 19, 220, 108);
// some text,
// some more text
insert into MixMax values (22,  5, 87, 1);
// and so on
insert into HooHoo values (8, 37, 222, 51);
// etc ...
```

Now, I'd like to yank the first numbers after the string `values (` into a variable, preferably in one go.

I thought of something like `:g/values (\(\d\+\)/let @a .= ', ' . submatch(1)` and would then have expected the register `a` to be `,13,22,8`.

Unfortunately, with this method, I only get the commas, but not the submatches, i.e. the register's content is `,,,`

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, submatch() only works with :substitute.

I *think* this is what you want.  There will be an extra comma on the end.

```
:let @a=''
:g/values (/normal f(l"Ayf,
:let @a=substitute(@a, ',', ', ', 'g')
```

Comment: Actually, that would be `:g/values (/normal f(l"Ayf,`, OP only wanted the first number from each value set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Together with wich's correction this is what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it on one line, you could do something like this:

```
let @a = '' | g/^/let @a .= matchstr(getline('.'), 'values (\zs\d\+, \ze')
```

The `:g` part runs the rest on every line (you can filter if you want, but `matchstr` is doing that anyway).  `matchstr` returns the matching string from the current line.  The `\zs` and `\ze` delimit the actual match, so that you don't get the 'values (' bit.

See:

```
:help matchstr()
:help getline()
:help \zs
:help \ze
:help :bar
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with `yi(` ?